# how to fetch image path from description element in RSS

Tags: php, xml, rss

Hello Sir I am trying to fetch image path from amazon RSS feeds but there are 3 different images in the description tag...I am using DOMDocument method to fetch data from RSS feeds ...When i am trying to fetch the image path its fetching the complete description(all 3 images path in one), but i only need 1st main image path to show it in my RSS feed slider... need help badly ...last date of project submission ...

Amazon RSS feed -- http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/rss/bestsellers/electronics/560834/ref=zg_bs_560834_rsslink

And Here is my test code to check images are working or not

```
error_reporting(0);
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/rss/bestsellers/electronics/560834/ref=zg_bs_560834_rsslink');
  $feed = array();
        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
         'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
         'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
         'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
         'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          'img' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(1)->getAttribute('src')
         );
        array_push($feed, $item);
        }   
        $limit = 10;        
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $img = $feed[$x]['img'];    
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date'])); 

    echo $img;
    echo "<hr/>";
    }
```

Comment: Wow, did you just paste an email from someone? _last date of project submission_ - I can't believe that I'm really reading this.

Comment: I see this is not your first question. You seem to not have lerned anything from previous downvotes.

Comment: its cool if you dont want to answer ... good day i will figure it out on my own

Answer (score 0):

This line assumes that the image is the 2nd item in the description. It is very likely to change as you're reading other RSS feed data.

```
$node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(1)->getAttribute('src')
```

Not only that, the description is generally saved in a CDATA block, meaning that the HTML found in it is one long string of text as far as the XML parser you're using is concerned.

What you really want is to get the description text, parse it as HTML, then get all the img tags (well possibly get the first one.) Ensure your code works in the event there are no img tags in the description.